# Do I need to reinstall language environments?

Tags: 11.10, java, wubi, ruby

I recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 (using wubi) and want to make it my main development environment.

I have `Java`, `ruby`, `gcc`, `haskell`, `python` (and the list goes on) environments, compilers and packages installed on the same machine under Windows XP.

Now my simple question: Do I need to reinstall the above for appropriate working on Ubuntu or can I use them by accessing the files on `/host/`?

Or does it differ for each language environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-install them.

Ubuntu and Windows talk in different ways, and because almost all of these are compiled, its even worse.

As such, you need to reinstall it.

*side note: This is why things like python and ruby are nice, because then you write your code once and it will probably run anywhere*